# Lifetime Extension of Temporary Object in Multithreaded Context

Tags: c++, multithreading, move-semantics, lifetime, temporary-objects

I have the following scenario:

```
void thread_func(const Widget& w) { /*does something here...*/ }
int main() {
  Widget w{ /* some arguments */ };
  std::thread t(thread_func, std::move(w));
  t.detach();
  // lots of other stuff down here ...
}
```

Now I know that temporary objects, when bound to `const T&` parameters in a function call have their lifetime extended until the completion of the expression in which the call occurs. But in this multithreaded context, does the "completion of the expression in which the call occurs" refer to the construction of `t`, or to the completion of `thread_func`, since `thread_func` is (at the very least, conceptually) called at the end of `t`'s constructor?

In a scenario with a single thread the answer is clear:

```
Widget h() { return Widget{/* some arguments */}; }
void g(const Widget& x) { /* do something */ }
void f() {
  g(h());
}
```

the lifetime of the temporary within the call to `g` lives until `g` has finished executing, since execution pauses within `f`, begins in `g`, and only resumes in `f` once `g` has finished executing. In a multithreaded environment, the answer is more confusing to me because construction happens in a single thread, but the execution directly following construction happens concurrently.

Comment: its not really so much about single vs mutlithreaded, but rather about forwarding paramters from a constructor of `t` to your `thread_func`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm not really sure what you mean -- could you elaborate a bit, please ?

Comment: what I mean is that the extra thread is not the thing that matters here. You can write some class that forwards parameters to its constructor to a callable just like `std::thread` does and the lifetime of the temporary will be the same

Answer (score 2):

This is not a lifetime extension situation. All temporaries live until then end of the *full-expression*, i.e. the outermost `;`.

`std::thread t(thread_func, std::move(w));` - this is a full-expression. So yes, the thread is starting when the expression is already ended.

Your thread is started with a reference to the original object, which must be keep alive for as long as it's needed in the thread.

Bonus notes:

- You can't `move` into an lvalue-reference. Your `std::move` has no effect. But even if you changed the function to accept an rvalue reference, it would not change the fact that the original object needs to be kept alive externally. Remember that `std::move` does not move anything. What would change it though is if you simply accepted it by value.

  ```cpp
  void thread_func(Widget w) { /*does something here...*/ }
  ```
- Detaching a thread is almost never needed. In your example the program will end when the main thread finishes, it will not wait for any other thread to finish. Consider `join`ing your thread before `main()` returns instead.

Comment: What I'm not understanding is how you're making the determination of what is the "full-expression." From the perspective of the main thread, a thread object is created, calls the passed function object, and execution is allowed to return to the main thread (i.e. outside of the thread's constructor). By the time the main thread reaches the call to `detach`, the expression has already ended, no?

Comment: @Pacopenguin suppose you wouldnt know what `std::thread` actually does. Suppose the line reads `std::foo t(thread_func, std::move(w));` and `foo` would be some class with a constructor with same signature. Then the situation would be the same

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I see what you're saying -- I guess my confusion was that in the case of a `std::foo`, you (probably) cannot advance past the initialization of `t` until you've finished *everything* in the `std::foo` constructor, function calls included. In the case of `std::thread`, you can.